# How do I get the computertemp applet working?

Tags: 11.04, notification-area, temperature

This is a little different than the common Natty temperature applet question. I've given Unity a shot and have reverted back to Ubuntu Classic. The one thing that is still not working is the temperature panel indicator (on 2 different laptops). It reports 'No Thermal Monitor Support' and shows a big red 'X'. The temperature sensors are working as GKrellM can still report temperature properly. Does anyone have a solution?

The specific applet is the 'computertemp' applet. After Jorge asked for more details, I tried the other one, the 'sensors-applet', and it actually works correctly.

Comment: You need to revise the title and contents as this has nothing to do with application indicators and instead involves notification-area (systray) applets.

Comment: I'm specifically trying to get computertemp working. It has a nicer presentation (graphs change color as temps increase, etc). I mention the other one as it shows that the underlying sensors are reporting values.

Answer (score 1):

Your first port of call should be the application [help page](http://computertemp.berlios.de/help.php)